# How to save states between route change in React

Tags: reactjs, caching

I have a simple application that shows the list of local hotels. Each list item has a `<Link/>` that redirects to another component, which displays the location on the map for that specific hotel. When switching routes, it seems that the `<ProductList/>` component gets destroyed and so do all the states in it. So every time when it makes new API calls and re-renders. I tried to save in local storage on each `componentWillUnmount` and retrieve it in `useEffect()` so that I can make API calls conditionally, and it works but sometimes doesn't work.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react";
import ProductItem from "../Components/ProductItem";
import axios from "axios";

const ProductList = () => {
  const [hotelList, setHotelList] = useState([]);

  // Get user location by IP
  const getCurrentLocation = () => {
    return fetch("https://ipinfo.io/json?token=MyToken").then(
      (response) => response.json()
    );
  };

  // Get list of hotels in specific location
  const getHotelsInLocation = (destInfo) => {
    console.log('destInfo is: ', destInfo)
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://booking-com.p.rapidapi.com/v1/hotels/search",
      params: {
        checkout_date: "2022-10-01",
        units: "metric",
        dest_id: destInfo.destId,
        dest_type: destInfo.destType,
        locale: "en-gb",
        adults_number: 2,
        order_by: "popularity",
        filter_by_currency: "USD",
        checkin_date: "2022-09-30",
        room_number: 1,
      },
      headers: {
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "booking-com.p.rapidapi.com",
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "MyApiKey",
      },
    };
    axios
      .request(options)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data.result);
        setHotelList(response.data.result);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentLocation().then((currentLocation) => {
      console.log("Current city ", currentLocation.city);
      const options = {
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://booking-com.p.rapidapi.com/v1/hotels/locations",
        params: { locale: "en-gb", name: currentLocation.city },
        headers: {
          "X-RapidAPI-Host": "booking-com.p.rapidapi.com",
          "X-RapidAPI-Key":
            "MyApiKey",
        },
      };
      axios
        .request(options)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response.data);
          let destId = response.data[0].dest_id;
          let destType = response.data[0].dest_type;
          const destInfo = { destId, destType };
          getHotelsInLocation(destInfo);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error(error);
        });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {hotelList.map((hotel) => (
        <ProductItem key={hotel.hotel_id} hotel={hotel} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductList;
```

How could I do so when coming back to `<ProductList/>` component, it doesn't make new API calls but just display the `hotelList` from the previous call.

Comment: I did not go through the code of the question but in case it helps, you can keep an array of the states in the redux store or wherever you keep the state so that you can use that array to check previous states. Its a pattern that can more or less give you the undo-redo feature for free

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, You need to keep the datas in the centralized store. For this, you have 2 options. One is using context api which is default react feature. Another one is using redux which is seperate package.

My opinion is, you can go with context api.

A simple example of context api is given below,

Filecontext.jsx

```
import { createContext } from 'react'

export const Filecontext = createContext({});
```

Formcomponent.jsx

```
import { Filecontext } from '../Contexts/Filecontext';
import { useContext } from 'react'

export default function Formcomponent() {
    const { setName, setEmail, setMobileno, showAlert } = useContext(Filecontext)

    return (
        <>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label>Name : </label>
                <input type="text" onChange={(e) => { setName(e.target.value) }} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label>Email : </label>
                <input type="email" onChange={(e) => { setEmail(e.target.value) }} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label>Mobile No : </label>
                <input type="number" onChange={(e) => { setMobileno(e.target.value) }} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="submit" onClick={() => { showAlert() }} />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Listcomponent.jsx

```
import { Filecontext } from '../Contexts/Filecontext';
import { useContext } from 'react'

export default function Listcomponent() {
    const { name, email, mobileno } = useContext(Filecontext)
    return (
        <>
            <p>Name :</p>{name}
            <p>Email :</p>{email}
            <p>Mobile No :</p>{mobileno}
        </>
    )
}
```

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Formcomponent from './Components/Formcomponent';
import Listcomponent from './Components/Listcomponent';

import { Filecontext } from './Contexts/Filecontext';
import { useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("")
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
  const [mobileno, setMobileno] = useState("")

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Filecontext.Provider value={{ name, setName, email, setEmail, mobileno, setMobileno, showAlert }}>
        <Formcomponent />
        <Listcomponent />
      </Filecontext.Provider>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

From the above example, The `Formcomponent` can be displayed in different route and `Listcomponent` can be displayed in different route. But even then, the datas can be retained with the help of context.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that

- You need the list of hotels in a global state instead of local.
- Use context / redux along with a cache policy in API calls and track your state changes.
- Skip the API calls based on your application logic and memoize the query result when needed hence in effect memoize the global state.

Answer (score 0):

Although caching with useEffect is possible, My recommendation is to  consider using **one of the query caching libraries** such as:

- [RTK Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview)
- [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/)
- [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/) (if you're using [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/))

From my experience if you're already using redux toolkit RTK Query will be the fit for you.

Answer (score 0):

First set up a global state manager. you can use redux, or context API. I prefer to use [zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand).
second config local storage to set visited component data.
third when you navigate to a new component retrieve a list of hotels visited and check if the ID exists or not. if yes no need for an API call and if no call it and save to zustand again.